# Join tables in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, transpose, flatten

I need to join these two tables into one

however, I'm having difficulty due to having duplicate registrations

*table 1*

| cpf | name | registration | password |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111111 | João | 1 | A |
| 22222222222 | Maria | 2 | B |
| 33333333333 | Pedro | 3 | c |

*table 2*

| registration | Margem | Port | Antecip | Obs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  | Inválido |
| 2 | 9 | 5 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 9 | 6 | 9 |  |
| 3 | 20 | 3 | 5 |  |

I want to join the two

and have as a final result this single table here:

| cpf | name | registration | Margem | Port | Antecip | Obs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111111 | João | 1 |  |  |  | Inválido |
| 22222222222 | Maria | 2 | 9 | 5 | 3 |  |
| 22222222222 | Maria | 2 | 9 | 6 | 9 |  |
| 33333333333 | Pedro | 3 | 20 | 3 | 5 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX({IFNA(VLOOKUP(F1:F10, {C1:C10, A1:D10}, {2, 3}, 0)), F1:J10})
```

[image]